# Clipping shapes in Silverlight2

Tags: .net, silverlight-2.0

I am writing a simple application in `SilverLight2`, which needs to draw an ellipse inside a canvas element - the ellipse position, height and width are computed during runtime.

What I need to fix is the clipping of the ellipse. If it gets to big it is drawn partially outside the canvas, above other UI elements. I want the bounding box of the canvas to be also bounding box of the ellipse.

I've made couple of tries with Clip property and rectangle geometries but with no success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight 2 clipping is not supported by all UI elements but only just a few of them:

- TextBox
- StackPanel
- Popup
- PasswordBox
- Border

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb979930(v=vs.95).aspx